# React: Create a new html element on click

Tags: html, reactjs, element

I've used React for a couple of weeks now but I have this simple problem that I can't seem to wrap my head around. It's about creating new html elements.

I would just like to know in general if the way that I went about it, is the "right way" or is there another preferred way to create new html element with a click function.

For some reason this problem took awhile for me to figure out and it still feels a bit strange, that's why I'm asking.

Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Overview.css';

import Project from './Project';

class Overview extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
   itemArray: []
  }
}

createProject() {
 const item = this.state.itemArray;
 item.push(
   <div>
     <h2>Title</h2>
     <p>text</p>
   </div>
 )
 this.setState({itemArray: item})
 //console.log(this.state)
}

render() {
 return (
   <div className="Overview">
     <p>Overview</p>
     <button onClick={this.createProject.bind(this)}>New Project</button>
     <Project />
     <div>
       {this.state.itemArray.map((item, index) => {
         return <div className="box" key={index}>{item}</div>
       })}
     </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Overview;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not a correct approach. **You shouldn't be generating HTML elements like that**, nor keep them in state - it is against React to manipulate DOM like that. You won't be able to utilize Virtual DOM is the first thing that I can think of.

What you should do **instead is keep all data that is needed for rendering in state and then generate the HTML element from there**, for instance

```
createProject() {
  const item = this.state.itemArray;
  const title = '';
  const text = '';
  item.push({ title, text })
  this.setState({itemArray: item})
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="Overview">
      <p>Overview</p>
      <button onClick={this.createProject.bind(this)}>New Project</button>
      <Project />
      <div>
        {this.state.itemArray.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="box" key={index}>
                <div>
                 <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                 <p>{item.text}</p>
               </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the explanation I appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad I could help;-)

Comment: Clean Solution! I like it :)